# dynamically load tree's child nodes on folder open

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm new to extjs and I'm trying to work on a Tree view.

I am building an "API Explorer" and there are simply too many nodes to send as a single json object (a few million nodes). What I wanted to do instead was send the first layer of categories as json initially, then on expand do an ajax request to get all of that category's children.

I'm not sure how to do this or if it's possible. Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually that is the "normal" way as suggested by the documentation. Have a look at any of the [Tree examples](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/tree/reorder.html).

You basically set up an [Ext.data.TreeStore](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore) with a Proxy, e.g. an [Ext.data.proxy.Ajax](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax):

```
xtype: 'treepanel',
loadMask: {msg: 'Loading...'},
store: Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'get-nodes.php'
    }
})
```

Each time the user expands one of the nodes, the URL will be hit with the parameter *node* set to the *id* of the expanded node and should return an array of the children of this node. These children must not have a *children* property theirselves, otherwise they would be considered already *loaded* and would not be loaded on expansion.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I need my tree to be nested many levels deep, is there some workaround for as you say "These children must not have a children property theirselves"

Comment: also, I see my GET request being sent, how do I tell it to send "?category_id=" the id of the node that I clicked on?

Comment: When I click expand, I don't see any parameters being sent at all

Comment: Let me rephrase that: Each time the user expands an unloaded node, the request is made. A node is unloaded if it had no children when it was loaded. So it's no problem to nest it many levels deep. In fact, some of them may have a *children* property but those node won't by dynamically loaded then.

Comment: I see now... Sorry! It uses node as the parameter.. .I can work with that. Thanks!

Comment: I think, currently the parameter name "node" is hardcoded and you cannot change it to "category_id".

Comment: Whoah, I set it up right and it "just works" amazingly better than I could have written it myself. Thanks again!

Comment: @AndreKR You can actually specificy the nodeParam on the TreeStore to override `node` as the parameter sent.